# Image software that breaks up single image into several images

Tags: software-rec, images

Here is my problem, I have a Canon copier that will also scan images and documents. I want to scan 5 images at the same time, this works but creates one giant image.

Is there a software program that will look at this single image and see that there are several images separated by white space and create 5 separate images?

**EDIT**

Cropping the images individually is what I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually quite a few scanners come with software that if you put multiple pictures on the scanner the software directs the scanner to scan the different pictures and save them separately.  You have to put space between the pictures for it to work.  If your scanner does not do this, you can use Photoshop Elements 7 or above and it has the ability to take a scanned picture that is actually multiple pictures and separate them into different files.  It works but is a hassle.  If anybody has another suggestion on a scanner software that will work this separation built in.

Answer (score 0):

nope.  not automatically knowing how to put the images in 5 separate files.

you either want to scan five times, one for each image.  Or use the crop function after you scan.

or you can use irfanview or gimp to crop the image into 5 parts

Answer (score 0):

If the five regions are always at the same position in the result image, you could use 
the `crop` operator of the `convert` command from ImageMagick and automate in this way.

If the five regions vary between images, then this is a much harder task, and I don't know about any software which does this.